# How to get object id from array using php mongod

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a array `$document` after query `findOne()`

```
Array
(
    [timestamp] => 1624382717
    [_id] => stdClass Object
        (
            [$id] => 60d2f531a5476f4eb220402b
        )
)
```

I want get `60d2f531a5476f4eb220402b` by use `$document['_id']->__toString();` but it never work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stdClass object does not have any methods by default, so you address the `$id` field like this

```
echo $document['_id']->{'$id'};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `_id` like this:

```
$id = (string)$document['_id'];
```